# TypeScript conditional types - returns one type at all cases

Tags: typescript

In my project I want to choose which function to apply to an argument based on its type.
SO there's a base interface and an extended one, that adds one property to the base one.
So I want to check if this added property is not `undefined` and pass it to the right function with the right type.
So here's the code (and  [image: Edit conditional types])

```
interface BaseType {
  field1: string
  field2: string
}

interface ExtendedType extends BaseType {
  id: number
}

const values: any = {
  id: undefined,
  field1: "String",
  field2: "Value"
}

const requestObj = {
  field1: values['field1'],
  field2: values['field2']
}

const request = values['id'] !== undefined ? {...requestObj, id: values['id']}: requestObj

type BaseOrExtended = typeof request extends ExtendedType ? ExtendedType : BaseType;

function baseFunction(request: BaseType) {
  console.log('Do BASE action')
}

function extendedFunction(request: ExtendedType) {
  console.log('Do Extended action')
}

function isExtended(item: ExtendedType| BaseType): item is ExtendedType {
  return (item as ExtendedType).id !== undefined
}

const baseOrExtendedFunction = isExtended(request) ? baseFunction : extendedFunction

baseOrExtendedFunction(request as BaseOrExtended)
```

But I do get an error

> Argument of type 'BaseType' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ExtendedType'.
> Property 'id' is missing in type 'BaseType' but required in type 'ExtendedType'.

And no matter what the value of `id` is it wants to execute `extendedFunction`. And always `type BaseOrExtended = BaseType`

Am I missing something about those conditions?

Comment: Oftentimes on stack overflow people have a problem. They think they know what a solution might be and they get stuck trying to implement it. Then they ask about their attempt at a solution rather than the original problem. What problem are you *actually* trying to solve here?

Comment: @JaredSmith I need to choose which function to execute (in real life they are Axios requests, `Promises` with following `then(....).finally(....)`) so I want to prevent duplication of that following code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the resolution of the type will happen in runtime, it cannot be statically determined.

Change your code to handle both cases in runtime like so:

```
const baseOrExtendedFunction = (request: BaseOrExtended) => !isExtended(request) ? baseFunction(request) : extendedFunction(request)

baseOrExtendedFunction(request)
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QCoE8AOKA3gLABQyyMwEANgCYCMAXMhmFKAObmXV30ATK3acQPMgF9y5UJFiIUAUQAekEPQj08hZBDUQNGNJhwFivZMHqsQAVwC2AI2jlpZcggD2IdsgBucLR2EMYAvMikFFY2yHYaENQgWgA0lvwMLMgARADKHNzZadEZQqzZAGpBIdluyJjI3r5gMmRNflAQAI4h7ADyTgBWyBFRfDSZrIHBoQDaAOSljPMAusXjAsIB1XOLE0Krbq3tYMidPaGnEdO9C9aryACEYRHxmklayAD8kQB0-+demABoMUjEpjsMHd6KtJKxAZcQa0wOYTFg+lBVOpNPQRsgUYQvDAzt0gXoDEZkFjDDidCgftSEtpUax0Fg6QBuVoweIIMDAHzIJymABivP5PgAFAj2KzTHSAJSRSztLy0CC-WheLiS+YAES8aAAgrklPU+QKQPMFUcPGQeSALYL9NitGLHRKQNLSZdWIzaeYlWNGj4MGqNVqdfrDf7PohPdbbeQHU6QFYMLH6JLgJAHH6KQHdAAfNFmQgK1g5iAOdNUgtaOnK6KdMB2KBp7O5+rGTOK37WJ4vOIJD70JNtUOnYXozH1+ju1N470XWWljGZpVhAB8T2AGbny6BSp+04gC89h8uStYLppbvFlsv7BtdtP67n58fMrACqAA)

Comment: Thanks, but if you check out the logs it looks like the `baseFunction` is not executed

Comment: Though it does solve the problem, why `request` is always treated as `BaseType`?

Comment: why do you think it's always treated as `BaseType`?

Comment: I'm making this assumption when hovering a variable using TypeScript IntelliSense.